# How to query for the products belonging to category and sub categories the correct way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Categories and Sub categories are independent models. And each category will have all the sub categories.

While creating a product, the admin has to select a category and the sub category.

Following are the models I have come up with

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end

class Sub < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :products
end
```

Here is the schema for the products

```
create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "price"
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.integer  "sub_id"
  end
```

The product is created with something like this

```
Product.create(name: "Messi magnet custom",category_id: 1, sub_id: 2)
```

And I am querying all the products that belong to a particular category and sub category like this

```
Product.where("category_id = ? AND sub_id = ?",9,3)
```

Is there any thing wrong with the associations I am having? And anything I could do improve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
  has_many :sub_categories
end

class SubCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
  belongs_to :category
  #Sub_categories table now have a reference to category, i.e., category_id column
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :sub #You need to add this too
end
```

Comment: Yeah, but if you go reverse way, you can't find it. Like `Product.find(2).sub` won't give you its related subcategory.

Comment: Ok @Kumar, Is there anything other than that you can find by having a glimpse at what I have shown. i am more worried about performance, should I need to add indexing for category_id and sub_id?

Comment: Yes, adding to index will certainly improve your performance. Its recommended for foreign keys.

Comment: One thing that worries me is, in the front end. I need to show the main categories in the header, and when hovered on main category, all the subcategories will appear, but it need not be the case that all the sub categories will have products associated. Is there a way that I could show only sub categories with the products, when hovered over  main categories.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116988/discussion-between-gates-and-kumar).

Comment: @Kumar why does product need to have a column `category_id` if sub_category already has it, unless the OP wants to denormalize for performance.

Comment: Think of a situation where there is no subcategory under a category, but it has products under it. Second, if you want to directly show all the products under a category, you can simply do `Category.find(x).products` instead of looping though all the sub_categorizes and then finding the product.

Comment: First case is valid, but second case is not. You don't need to loop over all sub_categories. Adding `has_many :products, through: :sub_categories` in Category will allow you to get products for the category with one single query.